# Is deleting an entity with a foreign key atomic?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is deleting an entity with children/foreign keys/`CascadeType.REMOVE` atomic? Do I need a transaction or I can omit it?

Comment: depends if Hibernate supports "auto-commit" style behaviour outside of a transaction. I know at least some JPA implementations do, though the JPA spec doesn't define that semantic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **always** need a transaction, it is not optional. There is no atomicity guarantee **ever** outside a transaction. Theoretically, if you gave the details of the exact database implementation and version number, it may turn out that in that special case the update is indeed atomic, but the fact would remain that this is no way to write reliable software.

You can [read over here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow) on Hibernate's attitude towards transactions.